# Import module from folder with deno

Tags: typescript, deno, import-maps

I have a npm module with a package.json at my folder ./module
When I import that in a file and run it with deno, it throws an error 'error: Is a directory (os error 21)'. Likely this is because my module does not contain an index.js file. Instead it contains a package.json that has some entrypoints pointing to the correct javascript files:

```
{
    "name": "my-module",
    "main": "../../dist/lib/module/index.js",
    "module": "../../dist/es/module/index.js",
    "es2015": "../../dist/es/module/index.js",
    "jsnext:main": "../../dist/es/module/index.js",
    "types": "../../dist/types/module/index.d.ts",
    "sideEffects": false
}
```

Running the same code with node.js works as should.
I tried several import-maps configurations but they just give the same error.

Is is even possible to import local npm-modules with deno without having to import a specific .js file but the package.json folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is is even possible to import local npm-modules with deno without having to import a specific .js file but the package.json folder?

As of Deno v`1.37.1`, it is not currently possible. A path to the local module file must be specified — in either the [import specifier](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/basics/modules/) or an [import map](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/basics/import_maps) entry.

This is being tracked on Github at the following issue: [denoland/deno#18474](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/18474)